# Read a bytes column in spark

Tags: apache-spark, encoding, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a data set which contains an ID field that is in an unknown (and not friendly) encoding. I can read the single column using plain python and verify that the values are distinct and consistent across multiple data sets (i.e. it can be used as a primary key for joining).

When loading the file using `spark.read.csv`, it seems that spark is converting the column to `utf-8`. However, some of the multibyte sequences are converted to the Unicode character `U+FFFD REPLACEMENT CHARACTER.` (`EF BF BD` in hex).

Is there a way to force Spark to read the column as bytes and not as a string?

Here is some code that can be used to recreate my issue (let column `a` be the ID field):

**Create a File with Sample Data**

```python
data = [
    (bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb0'), '1', 'a'),
    (bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb1'), '2', 'b'),
    (bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb2'), '3', 'c')
]

with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f:
    header = ["a", "b", "c"]
    f.write(",".join(header)+"\n")
    for d in data:
        f.write(",".join(d) + "\n")
```

**Read using Pandas**

```python
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv("sample.csv", converters={"a": lambda x: x.encode('hex')})
print(df)
#                  a  b  c
#0  baed858e91d4c7b0  1  a
#1  baed858e91d4c7b1  2  b
#2  baed858e91d4c7b2  3  c
```

**Try reading the same file using Spark**

```python
spark_df = spark.read.csv("sample.csv", header=True)
spark_df.show()
#+-----+---+---+
#|a    |b  |c  |
#+-----+---+---+
#|�텎��ǰ|1  |a  |
#|�텎��Ǳ|2  |b  |
#|�텎��ǲ|3  |c  |
#+-----+---+---+
```

Yikes! OK, so how about converting to `hex`?

```python
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
spark_df.withColumn("a", f.hex("a")).show(truncate=False)
#+----------------------------+---+---+
#|a                           |b  |c  |
#+----------------------------+---+---+
#|EFBFBDED858EEFBFBDEFBFBDC7B0|1  |a  |
#|EFBFBDED858EEFBFBDEFBFBDC7B1|2  |b  |
#|EFBFBDED858EEFBFBDEFBFBDC7B2|3  |c  |
#+----------------------------+---+---+
```

(In this example the values are distinct, but that's not true in my larger file)

As you can see, the values are *close*, but some of the bytes have been replaced by `EFBFBD`

Is there any way to read the file in Spark (maybe using `rdd`?) so that my output looks like the pandas version:

```python
#+----------------+---+---+
#|a               |b  |c  |
#+----------------+---+---+
#|baed858e91d4c7b0|1  |a  |
#|baed858e91d4c7b1|2  |b  |
#|baed858e91d4c7b2|3  |c  |
#+----------------+---+---+
```

I've tried casting to `byte` and specifying the schema so that this column is `ByteType()` but that didn't work.

**Edit**

I am using Spark v 2.1.

Comment: You found any way to fix your above issue. I am stuck with similar kind of issue

Comment: is it possible to tell me the solution you found?

Answer (score 1):

The problem is rooted in the fact that delimited files are poorly suited to binary data.

If there is a known, consistent encoding for the text, use the `charset` option. See https://github.com/databricks/spark-csv#features (I don't know of a good place in the 2.x docs where delimited reading options are described so I still go back to the 1.x docs). I would recommend experimenting with 8-bit ASCII, e.g., `ISO-8859-1` or `US-ASCII`.

If there is no such encoding, you would need to either transform the input to a different format, e.g., base64 encoding the first column, or manipulate the read data to get it back to what you need.

Comment: Can you provide some code that would work for the example in my post?

Comment: Not really, because I don't have the data and experimentation is required. Try passing a `charset = "ISO-8859-1"` option when reading the CSV with Spark.

Comment: I put the code to produce the data in my question. Thanks for the suggestion but I don't think this would work for this problem.

Comment: Why don't you think that reading 8 bit binary (as ASCII) would work? This approach essentially skips any decoding attempts by Java's string handling code.

Comment: @pault You found any way to fix your above issue. I am stuck with similar kind of issue

Answer (score 0):

How about storing it as base 64 encoding and decode it when reading it?

#### Storing

```py
import base64

data = [
    (base64.b64encode(bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb0')), '1', 'a'),
    (base64.b64encode(bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb1')), '2', 'b'),
    (base64.b64encode(bytes(b'\xba\xed\x85\x8e\x91\xd4\xc7\xb2')), '3', 'c')
]

with open('sample.csv', 'wb') as f:
    header = ["a", "b", "c"]
    f.write(",".join(header)+"\n")
    for d in data:
        f.write(",".join(d) + "\n")
```

#### Reading

```py
import pyspark.sql.functions as f
import base64

spark_df.withColumn("a", base64.b64decode("a"))
```

Comment: The point is to do this in spark. If I could modify the source data, I could rewrite it using pandas as shown above.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like some UTF-8 decoding is taking place; \xba is not a valid UTF-8 encoding of anything (see below) and is being replaced by \uFFFD, the "replacement character".  This is bound to happen: CSV is a text format, so decoders *have* to assume some encoding in order to interpret binary.

Let's take the start of the first value `EFBFBD` and decode it manually (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8 may help understand the encoding).

1. `EF` is `0b11101111`, so a 3-byte sequence (initial bits `1110`) starting with bits 1111.
2. `BF` is `0b10111111`, so a continuation (initial bits `10`) with bits 111111.
3. `BD` is `0b10111101`, so continuation with bits 111101.
4. Put them all together to get nybbles 1111 1111 1111 1101, which is FFFD.

***You cannot solve this problem with a text format like CSV***, unless you can get your CSV encoders and decoders to agree on some binary encoding format.  And that format will have be *binary*, not *Unicode*.  Note that if you have general binary values, you cannot even trust line endings!

You might as well use base-64 encoding.  Or, if you know line endings are not a problem (no `\x0a` and/or `\x0c` bytes) you *might* get by with a line reader.  But that is probably not recommended.